# ¿Cómo recuperar base de datos a partir del directorio data de PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, windows

Un servidor Windows server 2008 fallo. No pude realizar un backup de la base de datos pero pude recuperar el directorio `data` de la instalación de PostgreSQL. ¿Cómo puedo restaurar la base de datos a partir de ese directorio?

Lo que he intentado es crear instalaciones limpias de Windows y Postgres indicando que el directorio `data` de Postgres sera el que recuperé. Básicamente intenté [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305961/recover-postgresql-databases-from-raw-physical-files).

Nunca puedo iniciar el servicio de Postgres después de la instalación de Postgres. Pude identificar en la ventana de eventos de Windows el siguiente error cuando trato de iniciar el servicio de Postgres:

[image: Ventana mostrando visor de eventos con el error]

Mis primeras pruebas las realice con un Windows 7 y supuse que ese error se presentaba por tratar de recuperar el directorio en una versión de Windows diferente. Intente realizar lo mismo pero ahora con Windows Server 2008, la misma versión que la que falló, y sigue apareciendo el mismo problema.

He intentado todo y no he podido recuperar la información. Espero exista otra alternativa. Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: en realidad directamente por el administrador es complejo , debes buscar en la carpeta de postgres el pg_restore

Comment: pero `pg_restore`  es para restaurar un `backup`  de la base de datos. Como mencione en la pregunta no tengo ninguno y lo que pude recuperar fue el directorio `data`  de la instalacion de postgres

Comment: Busca el log de postgres al levantar probablente tengamos más pistas de como ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

Deberia bastar con dejar caer la carpeta data en el lugar donde la busca
el nuevo Postgres (que seguramente es el mismo donde la tenia el
antiguo, y seguramente es /var/lib/pgsql/data).

Obviamente con Postgres abajo.
Referencia: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20050128011759.GA11891%40dcc.uchile.cl